# How do I restore my Gnome theme defaults (after setting KDE theme)?

Tags: gnome, kde, themes

- **Ubuntu version:** 20.04.2
- **Gnome version:** 3.36.8

I've used Gnome for years, and recently installed KDE just to try it out. At some point I was trying different KDE themes and now, after I switch back to Gnome and try to use the default Gnome themes, my colors are wrong for certain applications. For example:

Calculator with Yaru (default Gnome theme):

[image]

Calculator with Yaru Dark:

[image]

As you can see, the background color of the history list didn't change, even though the text color did. It seems like some KDE theme might be continuing to override the defaults. Is there somewhere that I can find these overrides and delete them?

I've tried going into Gnome Tweaks and using the **Reset to Defaults** menu option, but that didn't change improve the situation. I also tried going into `dconf` and resetting all the values in the */org/gnome/desktop/interface/* settings to their defaults, but saw no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I deleted the theme folders in *~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/*, I got my Gnome themes behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-theme` in dconf to `Adwaita-dark` and that worked for me. Obviously you would have chosen a different theme name.